# Google Plus sharing shows error of invalid address ios

Tags: ios, swift, google-plus

I have followed all the steps shown in below link:-
[Google plus sharing link to integrate](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/#detecting_if_a_post_was_successfully_shared)

I have tried below code for setting sign in details:-

```
        var signIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance();
        signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = true;
        signIn.clientID = kClientId;
        signIn.scopes = NSArray(array: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"]) as [AnyObject]
        signIn.delegate = self
        signIn.trySilentAuthentication()
```

I have tried below code in appdelegate:-

```
        func application(application: UIApplication,
        openURL url: NSURL,
        sourceApplication: String?,
        annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool
          {
             return GPPURLHandler.handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
          }
```

I have set URL schemes and URL Identifiers as my bundle Id and it is same as Bundle ID mentioned in google developer console.

But I am getting error as displayed in screen shot:-
[image]

Please help me to resolve this error. I have tried all possible ways.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
signIn.scopes = NSArray(array: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"]) as [AnyObject]
```

Try [(as in the link)](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in):

```
signIn.scopes = NSArray(array: ["profile"]) as [AnyObject]
```

Hope it helps!